# How do I use the latest version of Zend Framework 2.3.5 using Composer PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What do I add in my Composer.json file so it downloads version 2.3.5 of the Zend Framework? I've tried reading the Zend docs but it doesn't mention Composer.

```
{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.6",
    "zendframework/zendservice-amazon": "2.3.5"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

After I run `composer update`, it gives me this error message:

> C:\Users\Ricky\graffiti-galore>composer update
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package zendframework/zendservice-amazon could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zendservice-amazon` is not part of Zend Framework 2, none of the ZendService libs are. Its latest version is 2.0.3, all versions are listed here: https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendservice-amazon

Answer (score 1):

In your require statement, it looks like you're using the wrong include for Zend. In your require statement:

```
"zendframework/zendservice-amazon": "2.3.5"
```

should be

```
"zendframework/zend-config": "2.3.5",
"zendframework/zend-http": "2.3.5"
```

Or if you want to avoid requiring a specific version number,

```
"zendframework/zend-config": "2.*",
"zendframework/zend-http": "2.*"
```

and for the part in `minimum stability`

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Comment: I found this page here which shows how to do what i want, http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you have listed for your `minimum-stability`? (located near the bottom of your composer.json file)

Comment: I did not have a minimum-stability so i created one and everything is working fine now. Oh ya, i had to lower the version. I'm using this and it works

{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.6",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "2.*",
    "zendframework/zendservice-amazon": "2.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}

Comment: Good to hear. I have had those minimum stabilities cause issues before as well. Especially when I'm just experimenting with a few new modules and don't want to change the minimum stability for my whole project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no version 2.3.5 for `zendframework/zendservice-amazon`, so obviously the install fails. Look at https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendservice-amazon to see the available versions and fix the version selector (I'd suggest `~2.0`).

You also don't need the `repositories` part in your `composer.json`, all the packages are also on Packagist, Composer's main and default package repository.